# Borel Cantelli Application - Durret Exercise

Tags: probability

Let $0 \leq X_1 \leq X_2 \dots$ be random variables with $\mathbb{E}[X_n] \sim an^\alpha, a,\alpha>0$ and $Var(X_n) \leq Bn^\beta$ with $\beta < 2\alpha$. Show that $X_n/n^\alpha \rightarrow a$ a.s.

First, I know that this question was already asked here: [$X_n/n^\alpha\to a$ almost surely if $EX_n\sim an^\alpha$ and $\mathrm{var}(X_n)\leq Bn^\beta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3402241/x-n-n-alpha-to-a-almost-surely-if-ex-n-sim-an-alpha-and-mathrmvarx-n/3665721).

We know that if $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(|X_n - X| \geq \epsilon) < \infty$$ $X_n \rightarrow X$ a.s. In this case, we need to show that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P} \left(\left|\frac{X_n}{n^\alpha} - a\right| \geq \epsilon\right) < \infty.$$ As in the question above, my attempt is to use Chebyshev's inequality, so we write $$\frac{X_n}{n^\alpha} - a = \frac{X_n - an^\alpha}{n^\alpha} = \frac{X_n - \mathbb{E}[X_n]}{n^\alpha} $$ I'm not really sure that this can be done since $\mathbb{E}[X_n] \sim an^\alpha$. If it can be done, we have $$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{X_n - \mathbb{E}[X_n]}{n^\alpha}\right| \geq \epsilon\right) \leq \frac{Bn^{\beta - 2\alpha}}{\epsilon^2} \implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{X_n - \mathbb{E}[X_n]}{n^\alpha}\right| \geq \epsilon\right) \leq \frac{B}{\epsilon^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{\beta -2\alpha}.$$ I'm stucked at this, any hint will be really helpful.

Comment: Did you look at the answers in the linked post? What did you find confusing about them? It is worth noting you have not used the monotonicity condition

Comment: I look at the answers. I don't get what happens in the second answer, how do we find $N$ such that $N^p<n<(N+1)^p$.

Comment: Those should be weak inequalities: $N^p\leq n\leq (N+1)^p$. You can always find such an $N$ since $\cup_{N=0}^\infty [N^p,(N+1)^p]$ exhausts the positive reals.